# Force browser to re-read ajax result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, browser-cache

Every day the contents of this request changes: the problem is that the browsers (IE and Chrome for sure), are ALWAYS displaying the OLD result (first get) until I clear the cache!

How can I solve this issue???

```
$('#q').keyup(function(){
    var param = $(this).val();
    if(param == ''){
        return
    }

    if(param != ''){
        $('#p_a').html('');
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {qty: param},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result){
                    $('#p_a').html(result);
                 },
        error: function(result){
                    $('#p_a').html('Error');
                },
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['qty'])){
    $cq = $_GET['qty'];
    $cq = $link->real_escape_string($cq);

    $GetP = $link->query("CALL GetPrice($cq)") or die('Query Error');

    if(mysqli_num_rows($GetP) === 1){
        while($p = mysqli_fetch_array($GetP)){
            echo $p['values'];
            echo $p['dates'];
        }
    }else{
        echo 'More Rows';
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT:

Is this jQuery function a/the right/best/good working solution? From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

`cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.`

Comment: Add `cache:false` to the parameters you send to your `.ajax()` call. You'd be better setting the `Cache` headers appropriately in PHP, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set `cache: false` in your `$.ajax()` call or if you want the caching to affect all the requests in a given page you can do

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

This will add a `_=32409035094` to the query string being a parameter named `_` and a value of the current timestamp. This creates a unique request string causing the request to be read from the server rather than the cache.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I was interested on the `Cache headers` on `PHP` that `Mike W` described on his comment. Can you say anything more about those headers? Thank you!

Comment: From what i have experienced its not the php cache headers in play here. The browser simply doesn't make the ajax request if cache is not set to false.

Comment: you can try including `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate")` and see if it changes behavior

Comment: Thank you! In fact it was the browser cache... ;-)